# install properly Selenium Server stand-alone binary?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello In order to overcome my diffulties in running Rselenium i' d like to install properly  a stand alone selenium server  (selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar) I extracted it in a folder in "program files" and gave the path in the "Edit Environnemt window" but my version of the server is not seen cmd [see respons in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddpAW.jpg)

Maybe i did something wrong in editing the path  but i can't find precise intructions to do so

Answer (score 0):

If you verified the path and set it in windows environment,
This error indicates either wrong path, or user permission in windows.

You need to lower user account control settings.
To do that, follow the below steps.

Go to Start and open Control Panel.
Select System and Security.
Under Security and Maintenance, select Change User Account Control settings.
Move the slider to one of the following levels:
Notify me when apps try to make changes to my computer.
Always notify.

Also, you can right click on the folder and check the security tab for the proper setting which allow to access the file.

Select OK to save your changes.
Select Yes when prompted to confirm the changes.